# Superposition of state and measuring the linear momentum: what are the possible outcomes?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, momentum, superposition

I have the following wave function (at t=0) which is a superposition of 2 eigenstate,
$$
\psi(x,0) = c_0 \sqrt{\frac{2}{L}} \cos\left(\frac{\pi x}{L}\right) + c_1 \sqrt{\frac{2}{L}} \cos\left(\frac{3\pi x}{L}\right)
$$

If we measure the linear momentum at $t=0$, how can I know which are the possible outcomes of this measurement and the respective probabilities.

In the position space, I know that
$$
\psi(x,0) = \sum_n c_n \phi_n(x)
$$
and $P(E_n) = |c_n|^2$ is the probability of measuring the energy $E_n$

But for the momentum, how can I know ? I should go in the momentum space right ?

So I can rewrite the wave function using exponentials,

\begin{align*}
  \psi(x,0) 
    &= c_0 \sqrt{\frac{2}{L}} \left( \frac{1}{2} \left( e^{ik_1x} + e^{-ik_1x} \right) \right) + c_1 \sqrt{\frac{2}{L}} \left( \frac{1}{2} \left( e^{ik_3x} + e^{-ik_3x} \right) \right) \\
&= c_0 \sqrt{\frac{2}{L}} \left( \frac{1}{2} \left( e^{i\frac{p_1}{\hbar}x} + e^{-i\frac{p_1}{\hbar}x} \right) \right) + c_1 \sqrt{\frac{2}{L}} \left( \frac{1}{2} \left( e^{i\frac{p_3}{\hbar}x} + e^{-i\frac{p_3}{\hbar}x} \right) \right)
\end{align*}

But then ?

Comment: Do you know what the momentum operator looks like in position basis?

Comment: yes, $\hat{p} = -i h \partial_x$

Comment: Can you solve for the eigenstates of that operator (in the position basis)?

Comment: $p\psi = \frac{h}{I} \partial_x \psi$ then $\psi = Ce^{ipx / h}$

Comment: So what are the eigenstates your given state made of?

Answer (score 1):

Yup, the idea is to indeed go to momentum space. A hint for doing so would be to write cosines in terms of exponentials (which is a natural choice for Fourier transform),
\begin{equation}
cos(\alpha x)=\frac{e^{i\alpha x}+e^{-i\alpha x}}{2}
\end{equation}

Fourier transform, F of an exponential can then be taken as,
\begin{equation}
F(e^{i\alpha x})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \hbar}}\int e^{ipx/\hbar}\cdot e^{i\alpha x} dx= \delta(p+\hbar \alpha)
\end{equation}
Hope that helps.

Comment: I rewrote the wave function using exponentials $\psi(x,0) = c_0 \sqrt{\frac{2}{L}} \left( \frac{1}{2} \left( e^{i\frac{p_1}{\hbar}x} + e^{-i\frac{p_1}{\hbar}x} \right) \right) + c_1 \sqrt{\frac{2}{L}} \left( \frac{1}{2} \left( e^{i\frac{p_3}{\hbar}x} + e^{-i\frac{p_3}{\hbar}x} \right) \right)$. But then how do I get the outcomes ?

Comment: Just use the fact that the Fourier transform of exponentials is a delta function (peaked at momentum values). Then as you have pointed out, the coefficients of these can be used to obtain the probability of the given momentum state.